# How to write a bracket function executing an arbitrary MonadUnliftIO within a RIO environment?

Tags: haskell

In the following case, I can directly use `initCass' fdsEnv` (of type `MonadUnliftIO m`) within a `RIO` `do` block:

```
initCass :: RIO FdsEnv ClientState
initCass = do
  fdsEnv <- ask
  initCass' fdsEnv

initCass' :: MonadUnliftIO m => FdsEnv -> m ClientState
initCass' fdsEnv = do
  let config = fdsConfig fdsEnv
  let logger = fdsLogger fdsEnv
  initCassandra (dbName config) (dbHost config) (dbPort config) logger
```

However, when I try to do something similar here:

```
runClientSafe :: MonadUnliftIO m => (ClientState -> m a) -> RIO FdsEnv a
runClientSafe cliFun = do
  fdsEnv <- ask
  bracket (runRIO fdsEnv initCass) shutdown cliFun
```

I get an error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘RIO FdsEnv’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          runClientSafe :: forall (m :: * -> *) a.
                           MonadUnliftIO m =>
                           (ClientState -> m a) -> RIO FdsEnv a
        at src/FDS/Database/Cassandra.hs:75:1-72
      Expected type: RIO FdsEnv a
        Actual type: m a
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        bracket (runRIO fdsEnv initCass) shutdown cliFun
      In the expression:
        do fdsEnv <- ask
           bracket (runRIO fdsEnv initCass) shutdown cliFun
      In an equation for ‘runClientSafe’:
          runClientSafe cliFun
            = do fdsEnv <- ask
                 bracket (runRIO fdsEnv initCass) shutdown cliFun
    • Relevant bindings include
        cliFun :: ClientState -> m a
          (bound at src/FDS/Database/Cassandra.hs:76:15)
        runClientSafe :: (ClientState -> m a) -> RIO FdsEnv a
          (bound at src/FDS/Database/Cassandra.hs:76:1)
   |
78 |   bracket (runRIO fdsEnv initCass) shutdown cliFun
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think the discrepancy is that in the first case `initCass'`'s m resolves to be `RIO FdsEnv`, so that makes sense. I guess what is really needed is a way to from `MonadUnliftIO m -> RIO e`, but not sure that is possible.

Comment: note: my workaround for now is to just implement `runClientSafe' :: MonadUnliftIO m => FdsEnv -> (ClientState -> m a) -> m a`, passing in the FdsEnv argument manually and using `initCass'` instead of `initCass` in the implementaiton

Comment: Can you explain why specializing the type signature to `runClientSafe :: (ClientState -> RIO FdsEnv a) -> RIO FdsEnv a` with the same implementation won't work?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr At some point, I tried it, and in the current context it was at least slightly problematic (I think) to pass in a desired function generating a `RIO FdsEnv a`, though I could probably have done so with a bit of extra work on the caller's side

Answer (score 0):

As @K. A. Buhr suggested, normally you'd stay in the same monad for bracket, in this case RIO:

```hs
runClientSafe :: (ClientState -> RIO FdsEnv a) -> RIO FdsEnv a
runClientSafe cliFun = bracket initCass shutdown cliFun
```

That being said, in another situation where you want the function to be polymorphic, but still unify with `RIO`, like you said in the question:

> I guess what is really needed is a way to from `MonadUnliftIO m -> RIO e`

you could use `RankNTypes` to solve this problem:

```hs
runClientSafe :: (forall m. MonadUnliftIO m => ClientState -> m a) -> RIO FdsEnv a
runClientSafe cliFun = bracket initCass shutdown cliFun
```